# How to run static_test to multiple python file?

Tags: python

I'm having 6 python file which does some functionality (all are in separate directory) and I'm executing static_test.cmd for each file separately.

My aim is to run static_test.cmd and I should get output for all python script.

Comment: You need to share some code, or describe your problem more clearly. Using vague phrases like "does some functionality", saying you want "output" and giving random filenames with no context will not enable anyone to help you with your problem. Be more specific about your problem, share code or examples of what you've tried, what results you got, etc

Comment: Get a list of the script names from the directory, create a `for` loop over the list and execute the cmd script against each file.